# How to fix blank screen when trying to render components with ' :is="component" '

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nativescript-vue

Writing in NativeScript-Vue for Android, I am trying to render a component based on button taps. I am using this [this plugin](https://www.nsplugins.com/plugin/nativescript-vue-global-drawer) to wrap the app in a global `SideDrawer` for quick navigation. I use buttons within the `SideDrawer` for viewing components. Here is what my `App.vue` looks like:

```
<template>
    <Frame>
        <Page actionBarHidden="true">
            <GlobalDrawer>
                <template slot="content">
                    <Label class="drawer-header" text="Drawer"/>
                    <Button class="drawer-button" text="Home" @tap="currentComponent = 'Home'" />
                    <Button class="drawer-button" text="Info" @tap="currentComponent = 'InfoPage'" />
                    <Button class="drawer-close-button" @tap="$drawer.close()">Close</Button>
                </template>
                <template slot="frame">

                    <ContentView>

                        <component v-for="component in pagesArray" v-show="component === currentComponent" :is="component" v-bind:key="component" />

                    </ContentView>
                </template>
            </GlobalDrawer>
        </Page>
    </Frame>
</template>

<script>

import Home from './pages/Home.vue';
import InfoPage from './pages/InfoPage.vue';

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            pagesArray: ['Home', 'InfoPage'],
            currentComponent: 'Home'
        };
    },
    components: {
        Home, 
        InfoPage
    }    
}
</script>
```

Here is the code in Home.vue, the default component I try to render:

```
<template>
    <Page>
        <navigation-bar />

        <GridLayout>
            <Label class="info" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center">
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span class="fa" text.decode="&#xf135; "/>
                    <Span :text="message"/>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
import NavigationBar from '../components/NavigationBar.vue';

    export default {
        computed: {
            message() {
                return "Test Homepage";
            }
        },
        components: {
            NavigationBar
        }
    };
</script>
```

If I directly use the `<home />` component within `<ContentView />` it displays fine, but when trying to display it dynamically, I get a blank page; no errors. Any thoughts on this?

I run the app on a connected Samsung Galaxy S7 using the NativeScript CLI. NativeScript-vue version: `^2.4.0`.

**Edit [01.20.20]: Detailed explanation on how I solved it.**

Read about it here: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/

In Application.vue, my GlobalDrawer looks like this:

```
<GlobalDrawer >
            <template class="global-drawer" slot="content">
                <ScrollView orientation="vertical" scrollBarIndicatorVisible="true" height="100%">
                    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                        <Label class="drawer-header" text="Menu"/>
                        <Button class="drawer-button" text="Home" ref="homeButton" @tap="homePageTap"/>
                        <Button class="drawer-button" text="System Oversight" @tap="infoPageTap" />
                        <Button class="drawer-button" text="Companies" @tap="companiesPageTap" />
                        <Button class="drawer-button" text="Calendar" @tap="calendarPageTap" />
                        <Button class="drawer-close-button" @tap="$drawer.close()">Close</Button>
                        <Label class="drawer-footer" text="By Bouvet" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </template>
            <template slot="frame">

                    <frame-hub />

            </template>
</GlobalDrawer>
```

The methods-section contains the @tap-methods:

```
methods: { 
    homePageTap(args) {
        this.$navigateTo(Home, { frame: "main-frame" });
        this.$drawer.close();
    },
    infoPageTap(args) {
        this.$navigateTo(InfoPage, { frame: "main-frame" });
        this.$drawer.close();
    },
    companiesPageTap(args) {
        this.$navigateTo(CompaniesPage, { frame: "main-frame" });
        this.$drawer.close();
    },
    calendarPageTap(args) {
        this.$navigateTo(CalendarPage, { frame: "main-frame" });
        this.$drawer.close();
    }
},
```

The < frame-hub > is a component (FrameHub.vue), looking like this:

```
<template>
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <Frame id="main-frame">
            <home />
        </Frame>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>

import Home from './../pages/Home';
import InfoPage from './../pages/InfoPage.vue';
import CompaniesPage from './../pages/CompaniesPage.vue';
import CalendarPage from './../pages/Calendar.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        Home, 
        InfoPage,
        CompaniesPage,
        CalendarPage
    }  
}
</script>
```

The @tap-methods in Application.vue changes the components that are renderered within the"main-frame"-element in FrameHub.vue. This way the GlobalDrawer is always on top, while the user is free to switch between pages.

I hope this helps anyone having the same issue. Also I'm sure this solution can be improved. Though I'm not currently working on this, but please let me know about improvements.

Comment: Do you want to show only 1 component based on the mouse click? If so why do you use a `for` then?

Comment: Any updates, news?

Comment: Hi @Steven! Thank you for the suggestion. 
I ended up dropping this solution and instead putting a 'hub'-component in the template named 'frame'. Then in this component I had a <Frame> with an id, which I then referenced in the @tap-handlers of the GlobalDrawer-buttons, using it to render components in. It works very well and I can use the frame-id globally. I got the idea from this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exE1WfPvAX0

I am still curious to why the first attempt did not work, but I suspect it has to do with how the plugin is structured. Also excuse my late response.

Comment: No problem I'm glad to hear that you fixed the issue!

Comment: I'm in the same issue but unfortunately the explanation is still vague. Can you include some kind of example? It could be much easier to follow. I really appreciate if anybody can help in this direction.

Comment: Hello @hgc2002. I have edited my answer to better explain my solution. Also take a look at the answer given by the creator of the plugin below. He's solution is the better one. Please let me know if you have any more questions about my solution.

Comment: @hgc2002 Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creator of [nativescript-vue-global-drawer](https://github.com/moeddami/nativescript-vue-global-drawer) plugin here.

The frame slot of GlobalDrawer contains a Frame element ([here](https://github.com/moeddami/nativescript-vue-global-drawer/blob/d7bacf4ada8895638f83e7cc03a5ea23812056ca/src/components/GlobalDrawer.vue#L10)) to control navigation inside the drawer as stated [here](https://github.com/moeddami/nativescript-vue-global-drawer#navigation), which means the slot accept only Page elements.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and is a better solution than the one I used. Also thank you for creating a great plugin!

Comment: @kristoffersyltedahl Glad it helped you!